# Python ( Selenium ) script for downloading PDFs, and when those aren't found it scrapes pages for similar information

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So essentially, I am writing a script that loops through a list of search terms, googles them, and downloads the first PDF it sees, but if it can't find one then it goes to the first link it finds and grabs it for scraping. I'm wondering if there's a way to use bs4 together with selenium in this case?

I also have a side issue of it continually running without stopping even once it reaches the end of the list...

Below is a sample of my code with most of the working parts included:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd


a = [
    "Learning Outcomes",
    "Program Handbook",
    "Program Goals",
    "Learning Standards",
    "Program Assessment"
]



b = [
    "Azusa Pacific University",
"Biola University ",
"California Baptist University",
"California Lutheran University"]

c = [
"computer science",
"physics"
"math"
]

keys = []

for x,y,z in [(x,y,z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:
    keys.append(z +" "+ x +" "+ y)

links_list = []

path_to_driver = r"C:\Users\whereverdriveris\chromedriver.exe"

download_dir = r"C:\Users\whereveryourdownloadsgo\file_dump"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": download_dir,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_driver, options=chrome_options)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)




while True:
    try:
        for k, key in enumerate(keys):
            start = time.time()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

            sleep_between_interactions = 5
            searchbar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
            searchbar.send_keys(key)
            searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            pdf_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]"))
            key_index_number = str(keys.index(key) +1 )
            key_length = str(len(keys))
            print(key_index_number + " out of " + key_length)
            
            if len(pdf_element) > 0 and  key_length < key_index_number :
                print("pdf found for: "+ key)
                pdf_element[0].click()
                time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
                print("downloaded " + key_index_number + " out of "+ str(len(keys)))
                
            elif len(pdf_element) == 0 and key_index_number != key_length:
                print("pdf NOT found for "+ key)
                print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")
                
                
                url_search = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}"
                request = requests.get(url_search)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
                first_link = soup.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text
                links_list.append(first_link)
                
    
                continue
                
            elif len(pdf_element) == 0 and str(keys.index(key)) == str(len(keys)):
                break
            else:
                break



        
    except IndexError as index_error:
        print("Couldn't find pdf file for "+"\"" + key + "\""+" due to Index Error moving on....")
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + str(len(keys)))
        continue
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("search bar didn't load, iterating next in loop")
        print(" pdf NOT found for "+ key)
        print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")
        
#       if this exception is raised enact beautiful soup
      

        continue
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        print("element either didn't load or doesn't exist")
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        continue
```

so, ideally it will search all of the terms and find the program review docs via pdf, but if that's not an option then it will create a beautifulsoup object and parse that for relevant information about each program I search for. I also found code from [here](https://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/scraping-search-results-from-google-search) that somewhat helps, it points in a generals direction but doesn't quite work when I attempt to add it to an for loop that loops over my key object.

So far, the code does loop properly, downloads PDFs into the file_dump directory, and even catches the first google search link text, but it doesn't properly click into the element in a robust way. I'm pretty new to XPATH and finding good selectors; I'm hoping for a solution that can work for any combination of search terms.

Also, It would be awesome for the code to also create new subdirectories for each new search result, with appropriate titles. I was planning on either dumping the parsed HTML data into either a pandas dataframe or a numpy array to make it easier to write to a csv/txt/excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why have a While True when you only want to loop a list.

Comment: it's for the try/except statement

Comment: Move the try into the for loop. You didn't have any way to break the while true.

Comment: couldn't I just include a break when a condition is met, like when the index runs out? Also, do you have any insight to my actual issue of it not properly clicking through and parsing links when it's not able to find a PDF?

Comment: You could do that as well but it's just extra code for the same output.

Comment: I mainly did it for flow control, I wrote it primarily as a test and originally it didn't run without the while statement--so it is a bit of a relic for that, sure.

Comment: I'll show you some code where the flow works decently.

Answer (score 0):

This works properly so far for what I can see it. It doesn't download them all.

```
for k, key in enumerate(keys):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

        sleep_between_interactions = 5
        searchbar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        searchbar.send_keys(key)
        searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        pdf_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]"))
        key_index_number = str(keys.index(key) +1 )
        key_length = str(len(keys))
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + key_length)
            
        if len(pdf_element) > 0 and  key_length < key_index_number :
            print("pdf found for: "+ key)
            pdf_element[0].click()
            time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
            print("downloaded " + key_index_number + " out of "+ str(len(keys)))
                
        elif len(pdf_element) == 0 and key_index_number != key_length:
            print("pdf NOT found for "+ key)
            print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")     
            url_search = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}"
            request = requests.get(url_search)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
            first_link = soup.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text
            links_list.append(first_link)

            
    except IndexError as index_error:
        print("Couldn't find pdf file for "+"\"" + key + "\""+" due to Index Error moving on....")
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + str(len(keys)))
        continue
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("search bar didn't load, iterating next in loop")
        print(" pdf NOT found for "+ key)
        print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")
        continue
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        print("element either didn't load or doesn't exist")
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        continue
```

Outputs

```
1 out of 40
2 out of 40
3 out of 40
4 out of 40
5 out of 40
pdf NOT found for computer science Learning Outcomes California Baptist University
computer science Learning Outcomes California Baptist University pdf not downloaded, moving on...
6 out of 40
pdf NOT found for physicsmath Learning Outcomes California Baptist University
physicsmath Learning Outcomes California Baptist University pdf not downloaded, moving on...
7 out of 40
pdf found for: computer science Learning Outcomes California Lutheran University
downloaded 7 out of 40
8 out of 40
pdf found for: physicsmath Learning Outcomes California Lutheran University
downloaded 8 out of 40
9 out of 40
pdf found for: computer science Program Handbook Azusa Pacific University
downloaded 9 out of 40
```

Comment: Ok, that was a nice quick fix to my secondary problem, but do you have any insights onto the rest of the question? Ideally, I would like it to click through the links and capture the websites for parsing in either a json/excel/txt file but even stored in an array would work for now

Comment: is it possible to click a link with Selenium and have it stored and parsed by BeautifulSoup? Somewhat like:

`google_search = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}"`
            `driver.get(google_search)`
            `url_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[1]/../../a').click()`
            
            `request = requests.get(url_search)`
            `soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")`
            `first_link = soup.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text`
            `links_list.append(url_search)`

Comment: Depends on how selenium opens it up but you can pass it's driver.page_source.

Comment: `html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser)` using this code got me an error: `InvalidSchema   `

Comment: html = driver.page_source soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser)

Comment: no error this time; but there's a huge messy output that doesn't seem to be from the page I'm looking to parse through--rather it seems to be returning the source from when the query was first sent to google.

Comment: `html_source_code = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
            html_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')` this helped, actually

Comment: I'm still hoping to find a method to reliably parse and extract the necessary information I need from these data. when I do something like this: `for title in links_list:
    if title == "title" or "<title>":
        print(title)` the results aren't the best, but it also seems to be stuck at the web search stage, not passing the webpage info that I'm actually looking for but just showing the HTML for when after the query was sent to google

Comment: It might need a wait in between.

Comment: `driver.implicitly_wait(10)
` or would you suggest `time.sleep()`?

Comment: I was recently met with a `JavascriptException` because a NoneType object was trying to be passed, should I just create another try/except and continue passed it or could this be solved with a longer wait in-between?

Comment: implicit waits over time.sleep