# BeautifulSoup/Python Problems Parsing Websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, html-parsing

I'm sure this may have been asked in the past but I am attempting to parse a website (hopefully somehow automate it to parse multiple websites at once eventually) but it's not working properly. I may be having issues grabbing appropriate tags or something but essentially I want to go to this website and pull off all of the items from the lists created (possibly with hrefs intact or in a separate document) and stick them into a file where I can share in an easy-to-read format. So far this is my code:

```
 url = "http://catalog.apu.edu/academics/college-liberal-arts-sciences/math-physics-statistics/applied-mathematics-bs/" `
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())

results = soup.find_all('div', class_"tab_content")
for element in results:
    title_elem = element.find('h1')
    h2_elem = element.find('h2')
    h3_elem = element.find('h3')
    href_elem = element.find('href')
    
    if None in (title_elem, h2_elem, h3_elem, href_elem):
        continue
    print(title_elem.text.strip())
    print(h2_elem.text.strip())
    print(h3_elem.text.strip())
    print(href_elem.text.strip())
    print()
```

I even attempted to write this for a table but I get the same type of output, which are a bunch of empty elements:

```
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for subtable in table.find_all('table'):
        print(subtable)
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why this may be the case? If possible I would also not be opposed to regex parsing, but the main goal here is to go into this site (and hopefully others like it) and take the entire table/lists/descriptions of the individual programs for each major and write the information into an easy-to-read file

Comment: you're right it has been answered e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285417/how-to-preserve-links-when-scraping-a-table-with-beautiful-soup-and-pandas

Comment: is there another answer concerning lists as well?

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach in that I also selected to combine bs4 with pandas but I tested for the presence of the hyperlink class.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://catalog.apu.edu/academics/college-liberal-arts-sciences/math-physics-statistics/applied-mathematics-bs/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for table in soup.select('.sc_courselist'):
    tbl = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    links_column = ['http://catalog.apu.edu' + i.select_one('.bubblelink')['href'] if i.select_one('.bubblelink') is not None else '' for i in table.select('td:nth-of-type(1)')]
    tbl['Links'] = links_column
    print(tbl)
```

With `BeautifulSoup`, an alternative to `find/find_all` is `select_one/select`. The latter two apply [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) with `select_one` returning the first match for the css selector passed in, and `select` returning a list of all matches. "." is a class selector, meaning it will select attributes with the specified class e.g. `sc_courselist` or `bubblelink`. `bubblelink` is the class of the element with the desired `hrefs`. These are within the first column of each table which is selected using `td:nth-of-type(1)`.

Comment: this works pretty well, but could you explain some of it to me? the tags `.sc_courselist` where did you find that? Also, is select_one('.bubblelink') a beautiful soup module? Lastly, where does `td:nth-of-type(1)` mean? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added a little more text

Comment: Thank you, if possible; I'm attempting to combine this solution with another found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360260/python-selenium-script-for-downloading-pdfs-and-when-those-arent-found-it/64361356?noredirect=1#comment113839660_64361356). What I really want to do is get my solution from that post and get it to default to code that's similar to this one; where if a PDF isn't found it scrapes for tables/other info and possibly store it in a new file(s). Not sure if it's possible without hard coding some selectors--which I've been trying to avoid for a robust answer

Comment: Hi, You should consider opening a new question, show what you have tried and state where you are stuck